# CKeditor - send back image or file URL to editor

Tags: image, plugins, ckeditor

I'm trying to implement my own image browser in CKeditor and I don't understand how to send back the url of the chosen image to the editor.

I have created a plugin to display a button in the editor toolbar, the button works fine and opens a div with my image browser in it. Until there, no problem.

Textarea used:

```
<textarea id="page_article"></textarea>
```

CKeditor init:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('page_article', {"extraPlugins" : 'imagebrowser'});
```

My browser displays a list of image and for each image I use a button to insert the image back into the editor.

```
<button id="action" image_url="[Real_Image_URL]">AddImageToEditor</button>
```

I capture clicks on button with this function:

```
$( document ).on("click", "button", function() 
{
// CAPTURE IMAGE URL
var img_url = $(this).attr('image_url');
}
```

What should I use to send back the img_url to the editor? I have tried the insertHTML but I can't get it to work.

Example:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.page_article.insertHtml('blablabla');
```

Thanks!
Laurent

Comment: Why you are trying to re invent wheel? You can use ckfinder or pdw file browser as well. They are well integrated with ckeditor.

Comment: Have you looked at http://ckeditor.com/addon/imagebrowser

Comment: Hello, yes I have looked at the other solutions you're mentionning but I'm using CKeditor in my own CMS where I already have an image browser so I'd like to avoid developing a second browser specifically for CKeditor. My image browser has categories, pagination, search and a couple of other features that are not available for those plug-ins. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through this documentation:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api

You will likely need call `window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, fileUrl [,data]);`